# Property "projects" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vite

I cannot wrap my head around this. I've looked at countless other issues, answers and I don't even understand the issue or what's causing it. I have a `projects.js` file with an array in it. When I `import {projects} from "@/projects.js"` I get the error in the title. When I add `setup` to `<script>` it works, but then I cannot export a variable that's needed for another component. What do I do? I've spent hours reading the docs & issues/answers. If someone could explain this problem to me like I'm 5 then that'd be very helpful also.

projects.js

```js
const getImg = (name) => {
    const path = `/src/assets/images/${name}`; //your imgfile
    const modules = import.meta.globEager("/src/assets/images/*"); 
    return modules[path].default;
}
export const projects = [
    {
        id: 5,
        date: "Aprill 6, 2022",
        title: "Muusika poe veebileht",
        image: getImg("music_instrument_store.jpg"),
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        date: "Märts 25, 2022",
        title: "Andres Kõljalg E-Portfoolio",
        image: getImg("andres_koljalg_portfolio.png"),
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        date: "Märts 4, 2022",
        title: "Andmemudelite & projekti planeerimine",
        image: getImg("datamodels_project_planning.webp"),
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        date: "Detsember 15, 2021",
        title: "Virtuaalne Instrument",
        image: getImg("arduino_chello.jpg"),
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        date: "5 November, 2021",
        title: "Ryan Reynolds E-Portfoolio",
        image: getImg("ryan_reynolds.jpg"),
    }       
]
```

ProjectsList.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="bg-black p-12 flex flex-col gap-20">
        <router-link to="/ProjectView.vue" @click="pId = project.id" class="z-10 hover:scale-[1.02] ease-in-out duration-300 hover-trigger" v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index"><div class="h-44 overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center">
            <div class="absolute z-[1] p-3 px-64 flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 project-card-txt-shdw h-44"> 
                <p class="text-5xl">{{project.title}}</p>
                <p class="text-lg">{{project.date}}</p>
            </div>
            <img :src="project.image" class="w-full ease-in-out duration-300 hover-target">
        </div></router-link>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
...blabla
</style>

<script>
import {projects} from "@/projects.js"
export default {
    Setup(){
        let pId = 0;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `projects` variable should be returned from the `setup` hook in order to be accessed by template and the `setup` hook name should be in lowercase format :

```html
<script>
import {projects} from "@/projects.js"
export default {
    setup(){
        let pId = 0;
      return{ projects }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either!

Comment: I got the issue, you've a typo it should `setup` not `Setup` with uppercase S

Comment: Wow.. that was it. Thank you. I was going insane